# How to add markers to a graph in a GUI? Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, graph, markers

I'm working on a GUI with Matlab, its almost finished and I would just like to add some small details and hope someone can help me with this.
In the GUI there is a graph with a spectrum in it, I am using the GUI to study different peaks in this spectrum. The user selects the peak to study by chosing a `starting_value` and `finishing_value` from 2 drop down menu.

What I want to do is add markers to the graph in the position of the `starting_value` and `finishing_value`. Has anybody any suggestions on how I can go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know the XY pairs it's as simple as adding another plot:

```
x = -5:5;
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y);

% Some arbitrary points for simplicity
starting_value  = -2;
finishing_value = 4;
start_idx  = 4;
finish_idx = 10;

% Add markers
marker_x = [x(start_idx),x(finish_idx)];
marker_y = [y(start_idx),y(finish_idx)];

hold all
plot(marker_x,marker_y,'or');
hold off
```

If you want to add annotations (lines, arrows, text, etc.), check out MATLAB's documentation on [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html).